# Vba loop column and change values afeter substring

Tags: excel, vba, substring

I am new to VBA.
I would like to loop through a column and perform a substring, changing the value of each cell.
Why this is not working?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("A8:A14")
Dim col As Range
For Each col In rng.Columns
    Dim new_date as String
    new_date = Left(col.Value, 5)
    col.Value = new_date
    
Next col
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the `Columns` when you need to loop over each cell:

```vb
For Each col In rng
```

I suggest a different variable name than `col`.

`col` as you have it would refer to the entire *column*, i.e. `A8:A14`. As that is comprised of multiple cells, its `.Value` is a 2D array that you can't call `Left` on.